# Java best practice for handling high amounts of stateful events

Tags: java, events, concurrency, event-handling, threadpool

I'm looking for a utility class or a best practice pattern to handle lot's of incoming stateful events in my application.

Imagine a producer that produces many events that are then consumed by an application that acts upon these events. Now in some situation the producer is producing more events than the consumer can actually handle, but because all events are stateful, it doesn't matter if some events would be missed, because the latest event contains all the information the previous events conveyed.

I have now written the following java code to handle these situations, but I'm unsure if this is the correct way of doing this, and if there isn't an easier, nicer, more secure way of doing this.

```
private static ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executorService = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
private final static Object lock = new Object();
private static List<EventData> lastEventData = null;

static {
    executorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized(lock) {
                while(lastEventData == null && !executorService.isShutdown()) {
                    try {
                        lock.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) { ... }
                }
                try {
                    actUponEvent(lastEventData);
                } catch (Throwable ex) { ... }
                lastEventData = null;
            }
        }
    }, 250, 250, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}


public synchronized update(final List<EventData> data) {
    synchronized(lock) {
        lastEventData = data;
        lock.notifyAll();
    }
}

public void dispose() {
    executorService.shutdown();
}
```

In order words, I'd like to get event notifications as soon as the arrive, but rate limit them to one event every 250ms and I'm only interested in the last incoming event.

I looked through java.util.concurrent for some hints / pre existing solutions but couldn't find anything that would fit my problem. The BlockingQueue seems to be very nice at first because it blocks if empty, but on the other hand, the queue itself is not important for me, as I'm only interested in the latest event anyway and the blocking on insert if full is not what I'm looking for either.

Comment: Could someone with more insight on concurrency than me take a look into the code and tell me if it actually makes sense, and possible pitfalls?

Answer (score 0):

The following model can support very high update rates, (into the tens of millions per second) but you only need to keep the latest in memory.

---

If you are taking a snapshot every N ms, you can use this approach.

```
final AtomicReference<ConcurrentHashMap<Key, Event>> mapRef =
```

When you have an update, add it to a ConcurrentMap.  The keys are chosen so that an event which should replace a previous one has the same key.

```
Key key = keyFor(event);
mapRef.get().put(key, event);
```

This way to map has the latest update for any key at a moment.

Have a task which runs every N ms. This task when it runs can swap the map for another one (or a previous empty one to avoid creating new ones)

```
ConcurrentMap<Key, Event> prev = mapRef.set(prevEmptyMap);

for(Event e: prev.values())
    process(e);
prev.clear();
this.prevEmptymap = prev;
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on how exactly the consumer thread should look like. I'm not sure on how to make the consumer thread wait for incoming events. There might be times when there a no events for a longer period of time (minutes, hours) and times with high amounts of events (100s per seconds).

Comment: I thought you said it runs every 250 ms, so it doesn't wait for events, it runs every 250 ms.  If this is not what you meant, can you clarify what you requirement is?  100s per second isn't very high and you should be able to support this with a plain queue.  If you have around 10K to 10M per second than you really need a Map as above.

Comment: Well in the above example I posted, I run a thread every 250 ms which, if there is no incoming event to be processed, waits until a new event arrives and immediately processes it. After the thread ends and another 250ms pass, I'll start the next thread and so on.

What do you mean by, using a plain queue? I don't want any FIFO based queue, rather I'd need a queue that only ever stores one event and is blocking on the consumer side, but non blocking at the producer side.

Comment: So you wait 250 ms and then process the next event immediately, and then wait another 250 ms and so one?  So one event goes through fast where as every event in between might have to wait for up to 250 ms?  I didn't say you *wanted* a queue or a non-blocking consumer, I was just saying it would make no real difference. ;)

Comment: Yes, you're right, if there are less than 4 events per second, every event will be immediately processed, but if there are more, I'll limit the amount of events to 4 a seconds (1000/250) but only take the last incoming event and discard all others (I don't need them).

Comment: @schneida so 4 times per second you can scan a map holding the latest value.